# pymc python change point detection for small probabilities. ZeroProbability Error

Tags: bayesian, python, pymc

I am trying to use pymc to find a change point in a time-series. The value I am looking at over time is probability to "convert" which is very small, 0.009 on average with a range of 0.001-0.016.

I give the two probabilities a uniform distribution as a prior between zero and the max observation.

```
alpha = df.cnvrs.max()  # Set upper uniform 
center_1_c = pm.Uniform("center_1_c", 0, alpha)
center_2_c = pm.Uniform("center_2_c", 0, alpha)
day_c = pm.DiscreteUniform("day_c", lower=1, upper=n_days)

@pm.deterministic
def lambda_(day_c=day_c, center_1_c=center_1_c, center_2_c=center_2_c):
    out = np.zeros(n_days)
    out[:day_c] = center_1_c  
    out[day_c:] = center_2_c  
    return out

observation = pm.Uniform("obs", lambda_, value=df.cnvrs.values, observed=True)
```

When I run this code I get:

ZeroProbability: Stochastic obs's value is outside its support,
 or it forbids its parents' current values.

I'm pretty new to pymc so not sure if I'm missing something obvious. My guess is I might not have appropriate distributions for modelling small probabilities.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to tell where you've introduced this bug—and programming is off-topic here, in any case—without more of your output. But there is a statistical issue here: You've somehow constructed a model that cannot produce either the observed variables or the current sample of latent ones.

To give a simple example, say you have a dataset with negative values, and you've assumed it to be gamma distributed; this will produce an error, because the data has zero probability under a gamma. Similarly, an error will be thrown if an  impossible value is sampled during an MCMC chain.

Comment: I see, but I'm unsure how the observations are outside of the distribution when I set to limits of the uniform distribution as the limits of the observed values?